# What exactly does this script do?

Tags: linux, shell-script, regular-expression

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in ./*.flac; do
  ffmpeg -i "$a" -qscale:a 0 "${a[@]/%flac/mp3}"
done
```

I found this script a few days ago to convert all FLAC files in the current directory into the MP3 format.

What I don't understand here is the `"${a[@]/%flac/mp3}"` part.
I think it replaces the ending flac with mp3 for the current filename. But what eactly does the `[@]` part do? Is it a regular expression?

Comment: @jasonwryan Not a dupe. It's not `%/` here, it's `/%`

Comment: @xhienne it's all parameter expansion; so it is a duplicate...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. There are two very interesting links in that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed it, `${var/%flac/mp3}` replaces the ending `"flac"` (if any) in value `$var` with `"mp3"`. `"${var[@]/%flac/mp3}"` would do the same on **each** element output by `${var[@]}` if `var` was an array.

Here, since `a` is not an array, you can remove `[@]` (I assume this is an heritage from previous attempts by the programmer).

Answer (score 2):

This does a simple shell expansion.  The variable `a` will iterate through every file matching the `*.flac` glob.

Since each entry will be a file (and I'm presuming no spaces in the filenames), `foo.flac` will be the expansion of both `$a` and `${a[@]}`.

The construct `${var/%foo/bar}` will replace `foo` with `bar` at the end of a variable `var`.  So it's replacing the extension `flac` with the extension `mp3` in your example to provide `ffmpeg` with the output filename.